# Stop Firefox extension popupset auto-hiding

Tags: firefox, popup

I am building a Firefox Extension. I have a popupset that is shown when a toolbar button is pressed and also have working code to close the popupset manually.

The problem I have is that the popupset disappears whenever I click elsewhere. I would like to disable this automatic closure behaviour. I'm sure I've seen a popupset or panel attribute to control this, but can't find a reference any more. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted. I'm a twit. Turns out there's a noautohide attribute that can be placed on a panel:

```
<popupset>
    <panel noautohide="true">
        <!-- insert further content here -->
    </panel>
</popupset>
```

I was searching for popupset attributes to no avail.